# How to retrieve content in Nexus 3.0 with script API?

Tags: maven-2, nexus, sonatype

How can I retrieve the content of the requested artifact for Nexus 3 like 
**/service/local/artifact/maven/content** in  Nexus 2 ?

I didn't see any script API in Intellij IDEA.

Which API can I use for that maven artifact operations like getting artifact, listing artifact names version numbers etc... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API for getting artifacts, listing artifact names, version numbers etc. The REST API will probably include these features when it is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, there is currently no REST API in Nexus Repository Manager 3, but one will be coming at a later date. An alternative for the time being is to use our Scripting API to accomplish what you need, as it allows you to roll your own REST API:

https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/scripting.html